# SwiftUI: List/ForEach background color

Tags: list, foreach, swiftui

In my List/ForEach (inside a VStack) I am displaying some data; I would like to change the background color based on those data; actually the data are processed in an external (same class) function; but if I try to recall the function from the body of course it does not work.

Any help/hint?

Code:

```
List {
                if products.count > 0 {
                    ForEach(products, id: \.self ) { prd in
                        HStack {
                            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                                Text(prd.qty ?? 0)
                            }
                            Spacer()
                        }
                    }
                    .onDelete(perform: deleteItems)
                }
                else {
                    Text("Non hai ancora inserito nessun elemento")
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                }
}
```

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You are right, sorry;

Comment: It's not clear from your code what you're trying to do. Do you want to change the background of one list item based on the quantity? Or change the entire list background?

Comment: I want to edit the background color of the list item based on the quantity, not the entire list background

Comment: Is there a response to this question anywhere, @MarcoGT ?